# Error : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. spring web app with jpa

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

```
RROR 15877 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

ERROR 15877 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure

ERROR 15877 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

ERROR 15877 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

I have these errors above in spring web app with jpa
here is my application.properties file

```
server.port=1337
# Configurations de la connexion à la base de données MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/pgi_db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=r68Mc72Ls7rmkJE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# Configurations JPA
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: It is unlikely that your MySQL server is listening on port 80. Try the default MySQL port instead (3306): `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pgi_db`. Let us know if that changes the error message. This change may be necessary - but not sufficient.

Comment: (Also I recommend not showing us any of your passwords in your questions. Change any passwords that you do show us - even for personal databases.)

Comment: thank you, about the password don't worry it's not the real password it just a random txt for demonstration.